# Can't remove slash in the end of URL (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

i read some Stackoverflow posts about my htaccess problem but i didn't resolve anything.
I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/$ /index.php?page=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+?)/$ /index.php?page=$1&p1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /index.php?page=$1
```

Every my site path needs the last slash (e: www.site.com/test/). If not, they go wrong.
How can i remove last slash without errors and both redirect to this format (in case there was the last slash)?
Thanks

Comment: try replacing `/$` with `/?$`

Comment: Thanks for replay! With `/?$` web site doesn't work with either `/` or without in the url

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you would want to remove '/' after 'page=', below should work. The RewriteRule pattern is matched against the part after hostname, which includes '/' . Note the '/' after **'RewriteRule ^'**.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/$ /index.php?page=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.+?)/(.+?)/$ /index.php?page=$1&p1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.+?)/$ /index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Thanks for replay! With `^/(...` web site doesn't work with either `/` or without in the url